# Mysql Join limit on from table

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I'm having the next mysql query

```
SELECT 
   `i`.`id_item`, 
   `c`.`id_category`
FROM `items` AS `i` 
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON c.id_category = i.id_category 
WHERE (i.id_page = '7') 
ORDER BY `c`.`id_category` ASC, `i`.`id_item` ASC
```

The items can belong to a category, or no category can be defined for them.
I need to limit the results from items table to X random values for each category, or X random values if no category is defined. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Group By" and then use limit it to x values ( LIMIT X). I am using X = 5;

```
SELECT 
   `i`.`id_item`, 
   `c`.`id_category`
FROM `items` AS `i` 
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON c.id_category = i.id_category 
WHERE (i.id_page = '7') GROUP BY i.id_category,i.id_item 
ORDER BY `c`.`id_category` ASC, `i`.`id_item` ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This limits me to 1 item per category (for 'GROUP BY i.id_category') or no difference if i use 'GROUP BY i.id_category,i.id_item' or not, i would need 5 per each category for X = 5

Comment: Lets say, there are 10 entries for that category. Now there has to be a column in the two tables which would be changing too for those 10 entries, or at least for some of those. You need to group by your result using it too. You can find this column if you use select (*) . Then use this column in your group by clause after i.id_category separated by comma.

Comment: if you use group by using company_id on this, it would return only one row although there more than 1 row. But look at the "status", it is changing too, so you need to group by it too , that is, group by company_id,status. 

| amount | status | company_id |
+--------+--------+------------+
|      1 | 88     |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |
|      1 | E      |       3688 |